# Is addTextChangedListener is method of EditText class or how it is related to textWatcher which is interface?

Tags: java, android

Is addtextchangedlistener is method of EditText class or how it is related to textWatcher which is interface?

Answer (score 2):

`Is addtextchangedlistener is method of EditText` - no, it's method of `TextView`. But `EditText` is a child class of `TextView`.

`how it is related to textWatcher which is interface` - `TextWatcher` is an interface for callback for *Text change* events in a `TextView`. This is only relationship.

Comment: ok then tell me where we pass value by using like  edittext.addtextchangedlistener(this);

Comment: @LuckySoni, to use `this` as a `TextWatcher`, your `this` has to implement it. You don't have to pass `this`, you can pass any object, which class implements `TextWatcher`

Answer (score 1):

Yes `addTextChangedListener` is method of `EditText` class and the method expects a object of `TextWatcher` interface implementation.

So if you want to use then implement `TextWatcher` interface like 
`public class CustomTextChangeListener implements TextWatcher`

Where `CustomTextChangeListener` is the name of class which implements it. After implementation you have to Override three of its method namely `beforeTextChanged, onTextChanged, afterTextChanged`.

Hope it helps.